# AWS ProfileCredentialProvides AWS SDK1 VS AWS SDK 2 JAVA

Tags: java, amazon-s3, aws-sdk-java-2.0, aws-sdk-java

Can someone please explain the difference between the two libraries below -

I have two pieces of code, both trying to list s3 buckets in an account.

JAVA 1 Library. that uses CredentialProvider from  [**com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfileCredentialsProvider**;](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/auth/profile/ProfileCredentialsProvider.html#ProfileCredentia%5B%E2%80%A6%5Dava.lang.String-)

```
            AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
                    .withCredentials(new ProfileCredentialsProvider("default"))
                    .withRegion("us-east-1")
                    .build();

            System.out.println("Number of buckets: " + s3Client.listBuckets().size());
```

Java 2 Library that uses CredentialProvider from

[software.amazon.awssdk.auth.credentials.ProfileCredentialsProvider;](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/auth/credentials/ProfileCredentialsProvider.html)

```
S3Client s3Client = S3Client.builder()
                   .credentialsProvider(ProfileCredentialsProvider.builder().profileName("default")
                    .build())
                    .region(Region.of("us-east-1"))
                    .build();
            System.out.println("Number of buckets: " + s3Client.listBuckets().buckets().size());
```

The Java2 library invocation succeeds and I can see the number of buckets printing.

The Java 1 library when used, always fails to load the profile from the config.

The ENV variables are set. I get this below exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No AWS profile named 'default'
    at com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfilesConfigFile.getCredentials(ProfilesConfigFile.java:158)
    at com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfileCredentialsProvider.getCredentials(ProfileCredentialsProvider.java:161)
    at com.s3.test.TestS3.testRead(TestS3.java:12)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:56)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.evaluate(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:100)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:366)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:103)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
```

Comment: This is not Java 1 vs Java 2.  It is versions 1 and 2 of the AWS SDK for Java.  (For what it is worth, Java 1 and 2 were both obsolete 20 years ago.  Before AWS even existed.)

Comment: I agree @Stepehen C. Thank you for pointing this out - I have updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

[credentials](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hl1py.png)

The above is how the credentials file should be defined. You are probably missing that first line. I guess one library expects the credentials file to be defined this way and one does not

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32868718)